# Uploading and processing multiple files using MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload multiple files on my web application. Hence I am using `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` class to loop inside each file. But I am getting an error stating -

> Error `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase>` does not contain a definition for 'ContentLength' and no extension method 'ContentLength' accepting a first argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This error is for all the properties present in  the HttpPostedFileBase class. I am trying to edit that class but it doesnt allow. I tried creating a IEnumerable of HttpPostedFileBase class in my ViewModel, but it fails again. What am I missing here?

Update - Code:
View

```
<div class="col-sm-8">                                  
 <input type="file" name="Files" id="file1" class="form-control" />
  <input type="file" name="Files" id="file2" class="form-control" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" name="Command"/>   
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files)
{
     foreach (var item in Files)
     { 
           if (Files != null && Files.ContentLength > 0)
           {
                FileUpload up = new FileUpload();
                up.PersonId = model.PersonId;
                up.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Files.FileName);
                up.MimeType = Files.ContentType;
                up.FileContent = Files.Content;
                bll.AddFileUpload(up);
            }
     }
     return View();
}
```

Comment: please share some code that you're using for processing HttpPostedFileBase items because it seems that you are trying to access to collection in a wrong way

Comment: please see my edited question, i have included the code. thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
foreach (var item in Files)
    if (Files != null && Files.ContentLength > 0)
```

You're using `foreach` to iterate the collection, but you still check the `IEnumerable` called `File` instead of each item. What you want is:

```
foreach (var item in Files)
    if (item != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
```

As a side note, you can filter out items using `Enumerable.Where`:

```
foreach (var item in Files.Where(file => file != null && file.ContentLength > 0))
{
    FileUpload up = new FileUpload
    {
         PersonId = model.PersonId,
         FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.FileName),
         MimeType = item.ContentType,
         FileContent = item.Content,
     };
     bll.AddFileUpload(up);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call `.ContentLength` on the collection, instead of on a file in that collection. Instead, try something like:

```
// given postedFiles implements IEnumerable<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase
foreach(var postedFile in postedFiles) {
 var len = postedFile.ContentLength
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code trying to access collection itself, but you need to access to collection item like this:

```
foreach (var item in Files)
{

FileUpload up = new FileUpload();
up.PersonId = model.PersonId;
up.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
up.MimeType = Files.ContentType;
up.FileContent = item.Content;
bll.AddFileUpload(up);
}
```